# How to put session php "username" and "gender" into url?

Tags: php, session, url

I have the session values "username" and "gender".  I want them to be in the url.  I want to click a link on test3.php and then the url will show the values for username and gender on test4.php. I am having difficulties with the url syntax.  Here is what I have for test3.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
echo "Username is " . $_SESSION["username"] . ".<br>";
echo "Gender is " . $_SESSION["gender"] . ".";
?>

</body>
</html>

<html>
<body>
echo <a href="test4.php?$_SESSION['username']&$_SESSION['gender']" ); >Submit Username</a>
    <!--This is test4.php-->


<?php
session_start();
$username = $_GET["username"]&$_GET["gender"];
//And then do whatever you want to do with it
?>
```

Comment: url params are `<a key=value` => `href="test4.php?username=<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>&gender=<?php echo $_SESSION['gender']; ?>" >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if they are session variable why you need to pass them in url you can simply get it in `test4.php` by

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$gender =  $_SESSION['gender'];

?>
```

Comment: I have already gotten them, but in order to bypass another login on a chat, I need to have the variables username and gender in the url.  This is what I am getting when I tried your suggestion Sean: https://englishjets.com/source/test4.php?username=$_SESSION[%27username%27]&$_SESSION[%27gender%27]  By the Way, Thank-you for your assistance.

Comment: you start the session where you want to get the username and gender.Update the question with what you have tried

Comment: Thank-you!!! I have been searching for days for how to do that.  I will put in the answer.

Comment: did you got it ?

Comment: if you're problem is solved mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark in the left side of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my problem:

```
<a href="test4.php?username=<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>&gender=<?php echo $_SESSION['gender']; ?>" >Submit Username </a>
```